# Writing between two cases brackets gives bad spacing

Tags: spacing, amsmath, line-spacing, cases

Consider the following code snippet. I have two big case brackets and unfortunetly the word 'and' in between doesn't quite places itself in the middle between both brackets. How can I solve this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{cases}
    x^{k+1} &= y^{k}+z^{k}\\
    y^{k+1} &= x^{k+1}\\
    z^{k+1} &= \frac{x^{k+1}}{y^{k+1}}
\end{cases}

and \\

\begin{cases}
    u^{k+1} &= v^{k} - w^{k}\\
    v^{k+1} &= u^{k+1}\\
    w^{k+1} &= \frac{u^{k+1}}{v^{k+1}}
\end{cases}

\end{document}
```

See the following:

[image: 'and' not in the middle]

Comment: **NEVER IGNORE COMPILATION ERRORS!** Your example does not compile as `cases` is a math construction and thus needs math mode. Try wrapping each `cases` within `\[ .... \]`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An observation and two suggestions:

- You're *badly misusing* the `cases` environment: The `&` symbols should *not* be used in the way you do in your code. They should be used solely to typeset a set of results in the first column and the conditions under which they are true in the second.
- Don't use `and \\` in text mode inside a math mode block. Either switch in and out of math mode explicitly or use `\intertext` to typeset a short snippet of text while in (multiline) math mode.
- If you decide to stay in math mode, don't leave all-blank lines.

Here's a solution that uses two separate math blocks -- observe the use of `\[` and `\]` to initiate and terminate display math mode:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for 'cases' environment
\begin{document}
\[
(x,y,z) =
\begin{cases}
    x^{k+1} = y^{k}+z^{k}\\
    y^{k+1} = x^{k+1}\\
    z^{k+1} = \frac{x^{k+1}}{y^{k+1}}
\end{cases}
\]
and 
\[
(u,v,w) = 
\begin{cases}
    u^{k+1} = v^{k} - w^{k}\\
    v^{k+1} = u^{k+1}\\
    w^{k+1} = \frac{u^{k+1}}{v^{k+1}}
\end{cases}
\]
\end{document}
```

---

And here's a solution that employs a single `align*` environment and an `\intertext` instruction. Not knowing more about your math typesetting needs, it's not possible to say that one solution is better than the other.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for 'cases' and 'align*' environments
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
(x,y,z) &=
\begin{cases}
    x^{k+1} = y^{k}+z^{k}\\
    y^{k+1} = x^{k+1}\\
    z^{k+1} = \frac{x^{k+1}}{y^{k+1}}
\end{cases}
\intertext{and}
(u,v,w) &= 
\begin{cases}
    u^{k+1} = v^{k} - w^{k}\\
    v^{k+1} = u^{k+1}\\
    w^{k+1} = \frac{u^{k+1}}{v^{k+1}}
\end{cases}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

---

Here's a juxtaposition of the outputs of the two recommended solutions. The *vertical* layout happens to be the same.

[image]

---

*Addendum*: If you need to align the two large opening curly braces as well as the `=` symbols within each group of equations, I suggest you drop using the `cases` environments and, instead, use `aligned` environments inside `\left\{ ... \right.` constructs. (The following code borrows from a since-deleted posting of yours.)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for 'align*' and 'aligned' environments and '\intertext' macro

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
&\left\{ \begin{aligned}
    f^{k+1}   &= (R_{\Omega\setminus\Lambda} + \mu_1 I + \kappa R_{\Lambda})^{-1}
                 \bigl( R_{\Omega\setminus\Lambda}(Pu^{k}) + \kappa R_{\Lambda}f_0 
                 + W_1^{T}(d_1^k - \tfrac{1}{\mu_1}b_1^k) \bigr)\\
    d_1^{k+1} &= \mathcal{T}^p_{\lambda_1/\mu_1}(W_1f^{k+1} + \tfrac{1}{\mu_1}b_1^k)\\
    b_1^{k+1} &= b_1^k + \mu_1(W_1 f^{k+1} - d_1^{k+1})
\end{aligned} \right. \\
\intertext{and}
&\left\{ \begin{aligned}
    u^{k+1}   & = (P^{T}\!P + \mu_2 I)^{-1}
                  \bigl( P^{T} (R_{\Omega\setminus\Lambda}f + f_0) 
                  + W^{T}(d_2^k - \tfrac{1}{\mu_2}b_2^k) \bigr)\\
    d_2^{k+1} &= \mathcal{T}^p_{\lambda_2/\mu_2}(W_2u^{k+1} + \tfrac{1}{\mu_2}b_2^k)\\
    b_2^{k+1} &= b_2^k + \mu_2(W_2 u^{k+1} - d_2^{k+1})
\end{aligned} \right.
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @Pazu - I've posted an addendum to show how to combine an `align*` with an `aligned` environment, using code from a since-deleted posting of yours.

Answer (score 5):

Don't just ignore compilation errors. Your example will immediately give an error if you compile it as the `cases` env needs math mode. This is a more correct way

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[
  \begin{cases}
    x^{k+1} &= y^{k}+z^{k}\\
    y^{k+1} &= x^{k+1}\\
    z^{k+1} &= \frac{x^{k+1}}{y^{k+1}}
  \end{cases}
\]
and
\[
  \begin{cases}
    u^{k+1} &= v^{k} - w^{k}\\
    v^{k+1} &= u^{k+1}\\
    w^{k+1} &= \frac{u^{k+1}}{v^{k+1}}
  \end{cases}
\]
\end{document}
```

Additionally, never use `\\` in the text, you're never going to need forced line breaks in the text (if you think you do, you're probably wrong). Also don't add blank lines around `and` like you do here, then `and` plus the two `cases` each forms their own paragraph. That is not what you mean.

Just wondering, are you by any chance using Overleaf for this example?